# Converting EPSG:3346 to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps-api, php

I am trying to work with some coordinates which are in `EPSG:3346` format. Now my understanding is that if I want to do something with these coordinates in Google Maps API, the format i need is `WGS84` (Is this correct?)

Is there library in PHP that can make these conversions?

Comment: As stated in this (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99999/coordinate-system-google-maps-api) answer, the google API has the EPSG: 3857. Having only the information of WGS84 is not enough to specify a coordinate system!

Comment: Have you checked this tutorial? https://phpcoord.net/en/stable/coordinate_conversions_easy.html

Comment: Google API is not based on EPSG:3857. The one who asked the referred question had such wrong assumption, but it was corrected in the answers.

Comment: @user30184 then what is it based on? I managed to fing a way to do it, and I convert to EPSG:3857 and the result of the conversion seems to put the point where it is meant to be. Later when I have time, I will add answer

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean with Google Maps API. Please add more details and code about what you are doing. The examples that I found are using EPSG:4326 lat-lon coordinates, for example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a library that you need : https://github.com/dvdoug/PHPCoord